# How do bulid local DNS server that transfers to ip address?

Tags: networking, dns, debian-wheezy

How to do that when type example.aaa moved to 123.141.151.1.

Example:
example1.bbb => 123.146.22.77
example2.ccc => 22.12.44.222
example3.bbb => 11.63.33.76

What I need to install DNS server on the raspberry pi? 
I want to every user of my dns able to use my domain shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get install bind9` installs BIND DNS server software. There are many tutorials in the Internet that tell closer how to configure it for proper DNS zones.

Comment: Please show me an example of use or link to tutorial

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto is one tutorial. With Google you can find many others.

Comment: I'd suggest using `unbind` for a home network… it should be a lot easier to be set up than BIND.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to go thru the trouble of setting up a DNS server just edit your hosts file   /etc/hosts

Add this

123.146.22.77 example1.bbb

22.12.44.222 example2.ccc

11.63.33.76 example3.bbb

Comment: This is only local, wants customers to set up wearing my dns